# Many domains using a single IP address with BIND 9.7

Tags: debian, bind, domain

I'm in the middle of migrating and configuring a web server with two domains (with one more in the future), and no sub-domains so far, but using a single IP address (for now). This type of configuration should be able to accommodate  many corporate email accounts created under one domain, and just a few associated under the other one (an e-store). I have doubts about how to set up this on an old Debian Squeeze 6 (Apache 2.2.16, BIND 9.7.3, Exim 4.72, Dovecot 1.2.15).

I've took some pointers from these sites:

- [Hosting multiple websites with Apache2](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/412/Hosting_multiple_websites_with_Apache2)
- [Handling mail for multiple virtual domains with exim4](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/140/Handling_mail_for_multiple_virtual_domains_with_exim4)

But I still can't find a good resource for the BIND configuration with many domains using only one IP. So, I want to be sure everything is in place before shutdown one server and start using the newly configured one, so any advice about multiple domains and multiple emails with one IP address, on the same server, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is very common. BIND can easily service multiple domains. Just create a zone file for each domain and then add each domain to your named.conf file like this:

```
zone "domain1.com" {
    type master;
    file "dynamic/domain1.zone";
};

zone "domain2.com" {
    type master;
    file "dynamic/domain2.zone";
};
```

There may be other options you may need in the zone {} block. BIND does not care that you are using the same IP in more than one domain or zone.

Comment: Yes, I know that's how I did it but, what about the reverse zones? I've read that those are irrelevant except in case of the Mail Exchanger.

Comment: most MTA's don't care about the reverse lookup, just that there is one (and that it don't contain something like "dsl" or "dynamic"). You can also use one generic name for multiple names, there's no rule that the MX for a domain needs to have a name that's in that domain; e.g. if you use Google to host your mail the MX is a google name and that works perfectly. The MX for microsoft.com is something.outlook.com.

Comment: @wurtel so, there's no need for a reverse zone for every single zone? do I need just one in any case? As I said, I only need two domains (which I have right now) but there's a third one on its way. I'm not sure about that one, but the first two goes with a lot of emails addresses associated. 
If I don't a reverse zone for those MX records, it's perfectly fine for me.

Comment: There *must* be a reverse lookup for your mail server's IP address, and the forward lookup of that name must match the IP address (so that you don't fill in a reverse that points to "apple.com" for example). However, apart from that there is no need for the name to have anything to do with the domain name used for the mail, so you can use one IP address for many mail domains.

Comment: Well, finally I got to the point of reloading bind, and this is what I get:
    # /etc/init.d/bind9 reload
    Reloading domain name service...: bind9rndc: connection to remote host closed
    This may indicate that
    * the remote server is using an older version of the command protocol,
    * this host is not authorized to connect,
    * the clocks are not synchronized, or
    * the key is invalid.
    failed!

Comment: In the context of reverse lookups, you cannot map an IP address to more than one host name. Only hyper secure MTA's (and some SSH/FTP/etc servers) care about the reverse lookup. Most will work, as long as there is *something*. Also, note that the reverse lookup table is managed by whoever owns the IP address. So in most cases, you need to contact your ISP to update the rDNS tables. I normally set things up so the rDNS entry for a given server points to the name of the SMTP server. I am not aware of any web server or client that checks to make sure the reverse and forwards lookups match.

Comment: @Kory After many days struggling with BIND, I finally got the webserver (with its respective domain) up and working as usual, seems like everything I did was OK, but it need a final step: reassign the DNS IP addresses to the old domain (which only the ISP admins can do). BTW, you were right: the original dedicated server didn't have a reverse zone, in that case the zone was created by me using cPanel, but in this server I don't have it, so everything should be done in the conf files (though I have Webmin installed), and of course, you were right about the rDNS tables.

Comment: You should try to make the externally visible reverse PTR entry for the IP address match the name the mail server uses to identify itself for outgoing email, to avoid issues with other hosts classifying your email as spam/forged.